# C Programming - Anomaly behaviour of while loop for float condition

Tags: c, while-loop, floating-point

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  float x = 1.1;
  printf("%s\n", "Hello!");
  while (x == 1.1)
  {
    printf("%s\n", "Hey there!");
    printf("%f\n", x);
    x = x - 0.1;
  }
  printf("%s\n", "Bye!");
  return 0;
}
```

However the output was (which I assume was not expected):

```
aps120797@XENON-PC:/mnt/d/Codes/LetUsC$ gcc C04Ag.c
aps120797@XENON-PC:/mnt/d/Codes/LetUsC$ ./a.out
Hello!
Bye!
```

To check if it accepts float condition or not, I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  float x = 1.1;
  printf("%s\n", "Hello!");
  while (x >= 1.0)
  {
    printf("%s\n", "Hey there!");
    printf("%f\n", x);
    x = x - 0.1;
  }
  printf("%s\n", "Bye!");
  return 0;
}
```

And I got the output as I expected.

```
aps120797@XENON-PC:/mnt/d/Codes/LetUsC$ gcc C04Ag.c
aps120797@XENON-PC:/mnt/d/Codes/LetUsC$ ./a.out
Hello!
Hey there!
1.100000
Hey there!
1.000000
Bye!
```

So, my question is, **what am I doing wrong in the first code**?

**UPDTATE**: Just figured out how to correct this error.
Appended the while condition like this: `while (x == 1.1f)`

Comment: @kaylum: Thanks! Just figured out what's wrong. Just appended the condition like this: `while (x == 1.1f)`

Comment: well, no. the problem is comparing floating point values for equality.  floats are always approximate, so equality checks often fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1.1` is not a `float` value, it's a `double` value.

When you write `float x = 1.1;` the compiler inserts an implicit cast: `float x = (float)1.1;`.

When you write `x == 1.1` the compiler inserts another implicit cast: `(double)x == 1.1`.

So effectively you are testing whether 1.1 is still the same value after casting it to `float` and back to `double` - i.e. whether `(double)(float)1.1 == 1.1` is true.

`(double)(float)1.1 == 1.1` is not true, due to floating-point rounding error. At least on my platform:

- `1.1` is actually `1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625`
- `(double)(float)1.1` is actually `1.10000002384185791015625`

and as you can see these two numbers are not the same.

Comment: Thanks! Just figured out what's wrong. Just appended the condition like this: `while (x == 1.1f)`